# Deploy two Django projects on one Xampp Windows Apache Mod_WSGI server

Tags: python, django, windows, apache, mod-wsgi

I want to deploy multiple Django projects on one server.
It is Windows 32 bit Xampp. mod_wsgi is 32 bit. python is 32 bit.
Django is ver 1.7.3.

I have read lots of posts and tried many things but I can't get past this problem.

The following error shown in the browser also indicates some version info.

```
Server error!
The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there was an error in a CGI script.
Error 500
localhost Apache/2.4.4 (Win32) OpenSSL/0.9.8y PHP/5.4.19 mod_wsgi/3.5 Python/2.7.6
```

I can successfully deploy one django application this way. There are no errors if I only deploy one, for example
c:/p2/xampp/htdocs/django/mysite

When I add the second project I get the below error and only the first project works.

I get the following error in the apache error.log.

```
mod_wsgi (pid=11184): Exception occurred processing WSGI script 'C:/p2/xampp/htdocs/django/apache/django161c.wsgi'.
~~~~~ some lines removed ~~~~~~
ImportError: Could not import settings 'mysite.settings' (Is it on sys.path? Is there an import error in the settings file?): No module named mysite.settings
```

---

Last two lines of My httpd.conf:

```
LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so
Include C:/p2/xampp/htdocs/django/apache/wsgi3.conf
```

---

My wsgi3.conf

```
############
listen 8986
<VirtualHost *:8986>
Alias /static/ c:/p2/xampp/htdocs/django/mysite/static/
WSGIScriptAlias / "c:/p2/xampp/htdocs/django/apache/mysite.wsgi" 
    DocumentRoot "c:/p2/xampp/htdocs/django/mysite"
    ServerName 127.0.0.1
<Directory "c:/p2/xampp/htdocs/django/apache">
    Allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
############
listen 8985
<VirtualHost *:8985>
WSGIScriptAlias / "c:/p2/xampp/htdocs/django/apache/django161c.wsgi" 
    DocumentRoot "c:/p2/xampp/htdocs/django/django161c"
    ServerName 127.0.0.1
<Directory "c:/p2/xampp/htdocs/django/apache">
    Allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

---

My mysite.wsgi:

```
import os, sys
sys.path.append('c:/p2/xampp/htdocs/django/mysite')
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'mysite.settings'
# works: https://www.pythonanywhere.com/forums/topic/1629/ # this is for changes to django 1.7 # 2015-01-23_Fri_14.13-PM
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

---

My django161c.wsgi

```
import os, sys
sys.path.append('c:/p2/xampp/htdocs/django/django161c')
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'mysite.settings'
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

---

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is:

There are two 'mysite.settings'
It should be 'django161c.settings' in the **django161c.wsgi**.

This fixed it.

Then it kept asking me to login repeatedly in each project.

I then added

> SESSION_COOKIE_PATH = "/django161c"

to the **settings.py** so that each site did not share the same sessionid cookie.

I did the same for the 'mysite' project.

> SESSION_COOKIE_PATH = "/mysite"

Also, I matched the compiler and versions of mod_wsgi

I used
python 2.7.9 apache 2.4 all 32 bit and all vc9 compiler
The mod_wsgi was downloaded from this post:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/modwsgi/SxedM5UKvic

I named the module    **mod_wsgi-442-ap24-w32-vc9-py279.so**

This way I know it is mod_wsgi 4.4.2, all compiled with vc9, for apache 2.4, python 2.7.9, all win32.